# can we use unix hardlinks on a mounted windows share?

Tags: linux, backup, samba, rsync, cifs

The `ln` command can create hard links on the mounted Windows share, but `cp -al` fails. Is this expected behaviour? I'm trying to save disk space by creating a copy on write style backups using `cowdancer`, `rsync` and `cp -al`.

```
backupuser@lan0:/mnt/backup/share$ mkdir a
backupuser@lan0:/mnt/backup/share$ touch a/b
backupuser@lan0:/mnt/backup/share$ cp -al a x
cp: cannot create hard link `x/b' to `a/b': No such file or directory
backupuser@lan0:/mnt/backup/share$ mkdir x
mkdir: cannot create directory `x': File exists
backupuser@lan0:/mnt/backup/share$ ln a/b x/b
backupuser@lan0:/mnt/backup/share$ ls -l x
total 0
-rwxr-xr-x 0 backupuser backupuser 0 Dec 23 17:33 b
```

Update: `ln` is actually creating a copy and not a real link

Comment: I think links are a filesystem level thing, and I'm not sure smb would expose it to the client.

Comment: Soft (symbolic) links have no special representation in the FS and can be represented on most (all?) filesystems, but hardlinks require specific FS-side support.

Comment: When I setup a samba server on Ubuntu and mounted it on debian, I was able to use cp -al (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 6):

Are you running SAMBA as server? Then look for "unix extensions" in "smb.conf" and enable them.

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#UNIXEXTENSIONS

With "unix extensions" enabled, SAMBA supports hard links, unix ownership information and mode for files and directories (aka. permissions).

However, this setting is a global setting. Therefore enabling unix extensions affects all shares (which might or might not be what you want).

Comment: Why can't I accept your answer with the green check mark?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently tested this using Windows 10 Pro as the server. My Linux system is running CentOS 7, which as of today ships Samba 4.4.4. Hardlink works well just like on a local file system.

Tests:

```
/mnt/f/tmp# mkdir a
/mnt/f/tmp# touch a/b
/mnt/f/tmp# cp -al a x
/mnt/f/tmp# stat a/b
  File: ‘a/b’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 16384  regular empty file
Device: 28h/40d Inode: 1688849861497214  Links: 2
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/   yanli)   Gid: ( 1000/   yanli)
Context: system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0
Access: 2017-05-17 14:31:43.564755100 -0700
Modify: 2017-05-17 14:31:43.564755100 -0700
Change: 2017-05-17 14:31:46.571727600 -0700
 Birth: -
/mnt/f/tmp# stat x/b
  File: ‘x/b’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 16384  regular empty file
Device: 28h/40d Inode: 1688849861497214  Links: 2
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/   yanli)   Gid: ( 1000/   yanli)
Context: system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0
Access: 2017-05-17 14:31:43.564755100 -0700
Modify: 2017-05-17 14:31:43.564755100 -0700
Change: 2017-05-17 14:31:46.571727600 -0700
 Birth: -
/mnt/f/tmp# echo something >a/b
/mnt/f/tmp# cat x/b
something
/mnt/f/tmp# mount | grep /mnt/f
//192.168.1.7/f on /mnt/f type cifs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=redacted,domain=REDACTED,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=192.168.1.7,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,user)
```

As you can see, file `a/b` and `x/b` have the same Inode number, indicating that they are hardlinks to the same Inode. Changing the content of one file affects the other file too.

`ln` works correctly too.

No special option was used to mount the CIFS; every option was default. I didn't do anything special on the Windows side either. It's just a default installation of Windows 10 Pro and a plain shared folder.

What I do not know yet is when this feature was added to CIFS/Samba client/Windows.
OP only said "Windows share", so it's not clear what version of Windows/Samba s/he was running. I hope my answer can help those who have trouble with creating hardlinks on CIFS mounted share backed by a Windows server; you may solve the problem by upgrading to Windows 10 Pro and at least Samba 4.4.4 (CentOS is not known for shipping the shiniest and latest code).

Comment: I have gone through the steps above from an Ubuntu 18.04 system running 5.4.0-48-generic linux kernel connected to a cifs share hosted from a Win 10 Pro version 2004 system and got the same results, hard links appear to work perfectly.